# How to set up a (not(contains)) with XPath in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, contains

I am using this PHP code to grab all text containing '$profile_name' under certain conditions.

It works fine as is, but I also need to pull all text which does 'not' contain '$profile_name' 
under the same conditions.

Like this:

```
$outputs = $xpath->query("//span[@class='profile' and   

not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))]/../div[@class='msgbody']");
```

Ok it appears this code does work, and the one below, but I've identified the problem to be actually this bit of HTML

```
<span class="profile">Jim Jones</span> to <span class="profile">Ronald Weasly                     
Stitch</span>
```

In this instance, user Jim Jones has written a reply to Ronald Weasly, but the expression I have mistakes it for Ronald Weasly, since that was the most recent span.

```
<span class="profile">Jim Jones</span> to <span class="profile">Ronald Weasly</span>

<span class="time">October 21, 2010 at 10:44 am</span>

<div class="msgbody">

<div class="subject">Jeeec</div>

are you developing applications with C+ or ASP, did you see The Social Network? i sense               
a huge opportunity for semantic analysts in the future.

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//*[div[@class='msgbody']]
         /span[@class='profile' 
             and 
               not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))
              ]
```

Comment: wow you lost me on that one. I guess so much changed from the original query, I can't make heads or tail out of it. I don't understand how part of it became a comment. I would assume I would have needed that to specify the div class to search in. I had meant the exclusion query to be a totally separate query, but only that I couldn't find the proper syntax for "not contains"

Comment: I was able to get it to return all of the names which aren't equal, but not the corresponding msgbody. with this code.                      `$outputs = $xpath->query("//*[div[@class='msgbody']]
         /span[@class='profile'
             and 
               not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))]");`

Comment: tried this `$outputs = $xpath->query("//*[div[@class='msgbody']]
         /span[@class='profile' 
             and 
               not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))]/../div[@class='msgbody']");
`

Comment: this code returns no results `$outputs = $xpath->query("//span[@class='profile' 
               and 
               not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))]//*[div[@class='msgbody']]");
`

Comment: this code returns all the names which are not equal. close. `$outputs = $xpath->query("//*[div[@class='msgbody']]
              //span[@class='profile' 
              and 
              not(contains(.,'$profile_name'))]");
`

Comment: I figured out the problem - code works fine - This HTML occurs occasionally `<span class="profile">CorrectName</span> to <span class="profile">WrongName</span>` a special case of a reply of a message. So, it grabs info the wrongname wrote, because it sees the Correctname as the class it should grab from - I'll get back when I find out a solution

Comment: @user734063: Sorry I was out of home most of the time. So, was my answer helpful?

Comment: @user734063: Glad my answer was helpful +1 for the good question.